# HTML 5.0 websocket not working

Tags: html, node.js, websocket

I have tried to make an application using node js

"GameClient.html"

```
<html>
<head>
<script language="JavaScript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
<head>
<body>
<script src="http://localhost:8888/socket.io/socket.io.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500"></canvas>

<script>


var canvas = $("#canvas");

if(canvas[0].getContext){
 var ctx = canvas[0].getContext("2d");
} else {
 alert("canvas problem");
}


$(document).ready(function() {

var down = false;

 $("#canvas").mousedown(function(){
     down = true;
  ctx.beginPath();
     socket.send("dn");
  });


 $("#canvas").mouseup(function(){
     down = false;
     socket.send("up");
  });


$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){
     if(down == true){

   ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';

   ctx.lineWidth = 20;
      ctx.lineJoin = "round";
       ctx.lineTo(e.pageX + 1, e.pageY + 1);
    ctx.stroke();
  socket.send(e.pageX + "1" + e.pageY);
  }


  });

//====================================================================



var socket = io.connect('localhost', {port: 8888});

socket.on('message', function(msg){

var mh=msg.n;
alert(mh);
if(mh == "dn"){
ctx.beginPath();
$('#add').append(" dn ");
}else if( mh == "up"){
$('#add').append(" up ");
} else{
arr = mh.split(":");
}

ctx.strokeStyle = '#000';
ctx.lineWidth = 20;
ctx.lineJoin = "round";
ctx.lineTo(arr[0],arr[1]);
ctx.stroke();
});





});





</script>

<body>


</html>
```

Socket-Server.js

```
// Require HTTP module (to start server) and Socket.IO
var http = require('http')
var io = require('socket.io');



var server = http.createServer(function(req, res){ 


 res.writeHead(200,{ 'Content-Type': 'text/html' });

 res.end('<h1>Hello Socket Lover!</h1>');
});
server.listen(8888,'localhost');


var socket = io.listen(server);




// Add a connect listener
socket.on('connection', function(socket){ 

    socket.on('message',function(msg){ 
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', {n:'Stopped'});
     });


    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('Server has disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('iran', function(data){
      console.log("**************" + data.todo + "******************");
    });

});
```

I am not getting the alert(mh); on the GameClient.html

Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your server code should be like this:

```
// Require HTTP module (to start server) and Socket.IO
var http = require('http')
var io = require('socket.io').listen(8888);


// Add a connect listener
io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){ 

    socket.on('message',function(msg){ 
        socket.broadcast.emit('message', {n:msg});
     });


    socket.on('disconnect',function(){
        console.log('Server has disconnected');
    });

    socket.on('iran', function(data){
      console.log("**************" + data.todo + "******************");
    });

});
```

also please change your html function to $("#canvas").mousemove(function(e) as well

```
$("#canvas").mousemove(function(e){
     if(down == true){

   ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';

   ctx.lineWidth = 20;
      ctx.lineJoin = "round";
       ctx.lineTo(e.pageX + 1, e.pageY + 1);
    ctx.stroke();
  socket.send(e.pageX + ":" + e.pageY);
  }
```

Try this and it will solve your problem.